# UILabel in iPhone 4S versus iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, storyboard, uilabel, iphone-4, iphone-3gs

I have been testing my app on the Simulator and an iPhone 3GS, and have most of the kinks worked out (I think!). I recently got to try it on an iPhone 4S, and there are some strange display issues with `UILabel`. These are generic `UILabel`, with System 17 font in all cases. I have used a storyboard to insert the `UILabel`. I'm running iOS6 on the iPhone 4, and iOS6.0.1 on the iPhone 3. On the iPhone 4, the text is truncated, and "..." is added. Anyone know why? And how to fix this?

Here's what it looks like on the the Simulator (looks the same on the iPhone 3): 
[image]
<sub>(source: [WhatDidILike.com](http://www.WhatDidILike.com/testing/TextSimulator.jpg))</sub>
.

Here's what it looks like on the iPhone 4: [image]
<sub>(source: [WhatDidILike.com](http://www.WhatDidILike.com/testing/TextiPhone4.png))</sub>
.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is the new AutoLayout feature fighting against you?

In any event, make your UILabel's *wider* in your storyboard, and/or add a "Minimum Font Size" autoshrink attribute for the text in the UILabel attribute inspector (which looks like this):

[image: Minimum Font Size]

Appears to be a new thing with iOS 6...

Comment: I don't see a "shrink to fit" checkbox in the attribute inspector. Can you point me more specifically? I'll try making them wider.

Comment: Making them wider works! A bit of a pain though. I wonder what issues I'll run into on an iPhone 5?!

Comment: Yep.  No more "shrink to fit" checkbox but instead a "Minimum Font Size" or "Minimum Font Scale" autoshrink popup choice.

Comment: Thanks!!! That works too. Doesn't actually seem to change the font size, but makes the problem go away.

Comment: Putting that value in is not supposed to change the font size, but if the text of the label is too big for the default size to fit, it's the "minimum font size" the OS will allow.